# How to reset changes made to one context of sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding

Tags: sapui5

I cant figure out how to reset changes made to one context of a sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding.

If I edit a context via setProperty and call hasPendingChanges() afterwards, it returns false (I guess because the ListBinding itself havent changed). But then, how am I supposed to reset the changes I made to this specific context without resetting all the changes for that ListBinding? I think I need a ContextBinding instead of a ListBinding, but I dont know hwo to get it without rebinding the context to a single entity.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3562

Comment: Thanks for linking the discussion @BoghyonHoffmann ! I'm author of this issue but forget to put a reference in here for other fellows who might run into the same problem.

Comment: The issue seems to have been fixed since https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d6440a45ec836d14f3264d518a31f073c849521b. Is the issue reproducible with the nightly release? E.g. bootstrapping with https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js

Answer (score 0):

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding%23methods/hasPendingChanges

> Returns true if this binding or its dependent bindings have pending property changes or created entities **which have not been sent successfully to the server**

So maybe the change was already sent to the server. Check your ODataModel if you are in `$auto` mode and a request is send the moment you called `setProperty`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using dedicated updateGroupIds, so there are no request sended to the server beforehand.